# Void value expression ruby using if

Tags: ruby

I have this block of code :

```
def load_logged_user
    hero, method = if session[:hero]
                     return Hero.find_by(id: session[:hero]), :session
                   elsif cookies.permanent.signed[:token]
                     return hero_from_cookie, :cookie
                   end
    @_logged_user = { hero: hero, method: method } if hero
end
```

And I'm facing a `void value expression` error on the line `end` of my if. I learned from the documentation that everything in ruby is treated as lambdas, so my question is : why is this not working ? What am I missing ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just drop the `return` from the code:

```
def load_logged_user
    hero, method = if session[:hero]
                     [Hero.find_by(id: session[:hero]), :session]
                   elsif cookies.permanent.signed[:token]
                     [hero_from_cookie, :cookie]
                   end
    @_logged_user = { hero: hero, method: method } if hero
end
```

Using `return` gets the code out of the function, which is probably not what you want to do.

Keep in mind that it is possible that since there is no `else` clause in your code it is possible that no assignment will happen and both `hero` and `method` will be `nil`

Comment: Thanks, but I can't return only two values without return, right ? Do I need to wrap them inside a hash ?

Comment: you can return as many as you like, just wrap them in array like `[hero_from_cookie, :cookie]`

Comment: @Bahaïka according to the Ruby documentation, a method has a *return* value, but an `if` expression has a *result* value. This distinction might help to understand the cause of your error.

Comment: Thank you @Stefan for this information : I do understood know what's the difference between the `return` and the `result`

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell ruby what will happen if hero is nil, so rewrite your code like this

```
 @_logged_user =  hero.nil? ?  false : { hero: hero, method: method }
```